# Error: Cannot find module './models/modela'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with my app, the files' tree is:

```
│   app.js
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│
├───models
│       modela.js
│       seedDB.js
│
└───views
    │   index.ejs
    │   landing.ejs
    │   new.ejs
    │   show.ejs
    │
    └───partials
            footer.ejs
            header.ejs
```

I am getting an error with models for Mongoose

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/modela'
Require stack:
- E:\Project\models\seedDB.js
- E:\Project\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\project\models\model-b.js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\project\app.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'E:\\project\\models\\seed.js',
    'E:\\project\\app.js'
  ]
}
```

My app.js file consist of-

```
const express  = require('express'),
    app        = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose   = require("mongoose"),
    projectItem = require("./models/modela");
    seedDB = require("./models/seedDB");

seedDB();
```

modela consist of

```
var mongoose   = require("mongoose");
var projectItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("projectItem",projectItemSchema)
```

seedDB consist of

```
const mongoose   = require("mongoose");
const Campground = require("./models/modela");

function seedDB() {
    projectItem.remove({}, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("all projectItem removed");
    });
}

module.exports = seedDB;
```

can anyone help me..
when I am writing everything in my app.js (start file), there is no error app is running fine..
getting this issue when I am making a separate Schema-model file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `seedDB` file you have

```
const Campground = require("./models/modela");
```

`seedDB` and `modela` are in the same folder, but your are trying to import it from `./models/modela`. So, replace the above line of code with this:

```
const Campground = require("./modela");
```